# Strange errors when trying to package to AZURE

Tags: azure

Little help here: I am uploading my site following the instructions on this [link](http://www.davidaiken.com/2010/07/14/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-web-site-to-windows-azure/).

My package command is this:

```
"c:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.6\bin\cspack.exe" "ServiceDefinition.csdef" /role:Nop.Web;Nop.Web;
pause
```

1) The first time I ran it, I got the error `"Could not access file hiperfil, access denied"`. I managed to disable Windows Hibernation and reboot. When I ran the command again:

2) `"Could not access file Pagefile.sys because it is being used by another program"`... I managed to disable the windows virtual memory. No pagefiles!. When I ran the command again:

3) `"Could not access c:\Program Files, access denied"`. I managed to give to Admin group full permissions, with no sucess... Before someone asks, I am running this command with Elevated permissions...

I am dealing with this problem because I want to deploy a working site to azure without Visual Studio.

If you need further info, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: your web role has a `physicalDirectory` attribute of something like `.` or `\`? (My hypothesis is that `cspack` is trying to put the entire contents of your hard drive into the package. My only guess as to why it's doing that is that it's in your `.csdef`.)

Comment: Hum... make sense... I will try that and I'll come back here later on. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running out of disk space by any chance?